# Do nas ssd drives used as cache consume nas drive bays?

Tags: ssd, cache

My current understanding of ssd cache for r/w is that I need two ssd drives.
If that is so, then a two bay nas, such as a synology 716+ drive is not appropriate for me.  I would need a model with at least three drive bays.

am i understanding ssd cache bay requirements?

Answer (score 0):

The [Technical Specifications](https://www.synology.com/en-global/products/DS716+#spec) for the Synology 716+ say it has support for SSD R/W Cache. If it's only a 2-bay NAS, then you will be able to get away with just one SSD used for Read Only cache.

If you want Read/Write cache on this device you will likely need to purchase an additional Expansion, either the 2-bay [DX213](https://www.synology.com/en-global/products/DX213) or the 5-bay [DX513](https://www.synology.com/en-global/products/DX513). As a Read/Write cache requires two SSD drives.

In the [SSD Cache Whitepaper](http://global.download.synology.com/download/Document/WhitePaper/Synology_SSD_Cache_White_Paper.pdf) they detail how these caches are set up:

> Read cache can be created with only one SSD. If larger read cache or read-write is required, two SSDs of the
>   same model and make must be installed in the server1
>   . For read-only cache, the SSDs are configured using
>   RAID 0. For read-write cache, SSDs are configured using RAID 1 to ensure data integrity in case one SSD fails.

If you want to use a Read/Write cache on your Synology NAS it would probably be better to start with a larger than 2-bay NAS from their product range.

Comment: AFAIK some Synology devices support adding eSATA or USB3 SSDs for caching. Pretty sure my DS1515+ can do that :-)

Comment: @JensEhrich That's a good point. The drive he has does support USB3.0 and eSATA, but the spec doesn't mention if they can be used for SSD Cache.

Comment: M. Frank,  Your comment about only one SSD is used for R/W is incorrect. If you go to the SSD Cache Whitepaper that you referred to me, you will see the following sentence: 
"Read cache can be created with only one SSD.If larger read cache or readwrite is required two SSDs of the same model and make 
must be installed in the server. Secondly, ssd comes in several versions, one being PCIe.  Secondly, regarding your comment, "where else are you going to put it".....If the NAS had a PCIe bus with two slots, then my SSD cache would not use up any of the drive bays!!!

.

Comment: But you specifically mentioned the 716+ model. Did you want a more general answer?

Comment: @whburling I've looked into it further and it seems you are right. I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @MichaelFrank I happened to be on the phone with Synology support yesterday and confirmed that neither eSATA nor USB3 devices can be used for cache. However, SSD drives in an expansion module (also connected via eSATA) can be used as cache. So there's no way to have R/W cache in a 2 bay enclosure, unless there is an expansion option for the one in question.

Comment: @jensehrich Good thing I covered that in my answer. The DX312 and DX512 both attach to the DS716+ in question here. :)